# Using 'this' to find the final row in a table header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using stupidtable (http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/) to add sorting to a table. I use a callback to add an appropriate up or down arrow to show which column has been used for the sort and whether it is ascending or descending.

The original event handler used the code:

```
table.bind('aftertablesort', function (event, data) {

    // data.column - the index of the column sorted after a click
    // data.direction - the sorting direction (either asc or desc)

    var th = $(this).find("th");
    th.find(".arrow").remove();
    var arrow = data.direction === "asc" ? "↑" : "↓";
    th.eq(data.column).append('<span class="arrow">' + arrow +'</span>');
});
```

This works fine when there is only one row of headers, but if there are multiple rows it doesn't because it finds the first header row not the last.

I'm struggling to find out how to find the bottom row, following another thread I tried:

```
var th = $(this + ' thead tr:last').find("th");
```

But this gives a syntax error, I guess because I am not using 'this' properly. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Steph

Comment: this refers to an DomNode. You should properly use `$(this).find` or `$(this).is` instead of `$(this + '...')` which is wrong Cause you are pushing the object (this) to a string `[object HTMLTableElement]  ...`

Comment: As soon as I read this a light dawned, I went away and wrote `var th = $(this).find("thead tr:last th");` and it worked perfectly. Came back and saw it has been suggested as an answer as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not a string, but a DOM element.

You could use it as a context selector like this :

```
var th = $('thead tr:last', this).find("th");
```

But `.find` is faster than context, so use this :

```
var th = $(this).find("thead tr:last th");
```

Comment: `$(selector, context)` is simple rewriting to `$(context).find(selector)` in the source. I hardly find a big performance buff here. But because jQuery is using `$(context).find(selector)` I think it's best practice to do so.

Comment: It is, check this link : http://addyosmani.com/blog/8-jquery-performance-tips/ Step number 6. The article is old, but it still true. Using context selector is an addition non-needed function call.

Comment: As is what I'm saying: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.init Look under `// HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))`

Answer (score 2):

you cant combine an object with a string to build a selector. 
try this:

```
var th = $(this).find('thead tr:last').find("th");
```

Answer (score 0):

if `this` referes to your table you should use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var th = $(this).find('thead tr:last')
```

The following line

```
$(this + ' thead tr:last')
```

Will not work, because `this` is an object and you are mixing with a string, which will result in

```
$("[object HTMLTableElement] thead tr:last")
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know that `thead` is for the header section of a table. So when ask "bottom row" are you sure it's the header you want or the body?

Find the last header row if `this` is a parent.

```
var last_header_row = $(this).find("thead").last("tr");
```

To find the last row in the body if `this` is a parent.

```
var last_body_row = $(this).find("tbody").last("tr");
```

Note, that the `this` reference is in the context of the callback function for the event. Without knowing what that context is we can't assure that it's a DOM element reference.

If you have a reference from inside the table, where `this` is a `tr` or something. Replace the call to `find(..)` with `closest(..)`